# Kotlin: LayoutInflate from another layout file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, layout

I want to `findViewById()` in Kotlin from another layout file, but firstly I need to inflate the view of that file, right?

```java
val newView = LayoutInflater.from().inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null)
```

I'm not sure what to put in the `from` brackets, because apparently my `parent` is null, so I cant use parent.context.
This is my setContentViewPart:

```
 binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
```

What can I put in .from(), or is there any other method to findViewById from another layout file?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context for why you want to do this? Are you going to inflate the other layout and add it to the current layout? Or are you trying to do something like set a view property in another activity/fragment (which you can't do this way)?

Comment: I want to set viewpager to tab layout

Comment: That's not really very specific, but that should not require inflating anything. The ViewPager and TabLayout should already be present in the current activity layout. You should post more details about the *actual* problem you are trying to solve, not your attempted workaround involving inflating views (see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))